# Save and Load UISwitch state

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I want to save the swtich state and load it when the program restarted.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:switchControl.on forKey:@"switch"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

This is the saving part

```
BOOL test= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switch"];
NSLog(@"%@",test?@"YES":@"NO");
if(test == YES)
    [switchControl setOn:YES animated:YES];
else
     [switchControl setOn:NO animated:YES];
```

This is the part that is need to be set the switch to its value.I did this in viewdidload method because when i close the application and restarted it i want the state of the switch set the saved part .

But it is still showing the default part can u help me to set it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you create the switch as an IBOutlet with properties? If so, I think your problem is that you dont refer to your `switchControl` as `self.switchControl`.

Then your correct saving statement will become

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:self.switchControl.on forKey:@"switch"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

I'd move the part that sets the switch into `viewWillAppear` and do it like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  BOOL test= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switch"];
  NSLog(@"%@",test?@"YES":@"NO");
  [self.switchControl setOn:test animated:YES];
}
```

I took out an unnecessary if-statement for you, too.

Comment: it works i am not using the Iboulet part so i dont use self :) thanks